# Loader Using HttpClient Interceptor Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular4-httpclient

How can i implement a loader using Angular 4 HttpClient Interceptor? I have done the login and attaching the authorization header and i wonder if i can also do the "loader function" if some data is loading in the process? I would like to attached a icon loader that signals if some data is loading. Here's my authinterceptor below by the way.

```
export class GithubAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'token')
    });
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be done in a number of ways. Have you created a loader yet? What exactly are we working with? The fact that you only show the interceptor makes me assume you have a loader in place?

Comment: @JunKang. Not yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the sake of this question, I'm not going to go through creating a loader, and just talk about how you would implement an existing loader into the interceptor. Every time you make a call, the `intercept()` function is called. That means, at the beginning of the `intercept()` function, you should show a loader using an injected `LoaderService` whos job will be to show and hide a loader based on whether a call has been made and when it has been completed.

```
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {
}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  this.loaderService.show();
  const authReq = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'token')
  });
  return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

Then, you have to make sure the loader is hidden after the call has been completed. You can do this with the `do` operator.

```
return next.handle(authReq)
  .do(
  (response) => {
    if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
      this.loaderService.hide();
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    this.loaderService.hide();
  });
```

Make sure to import the `do` operator: `import "rxjs/add/operator/do";`

Why do you have to check `if (event instanceof HttpResponse)`? This is because the `HttpInterceptor` intercepts ALL `HttpEvent`s. This includes the `HttpSentEvent`, `HttpProgressEvent`, etc, but you don't want to hide the loader upon receiving those types of events. Only once you actually receive a response. And, of course, you will hide the loader if you receive an error. You can also put any other processes you may want to happen upon receive a response here in the `do` block. For example, storing an Auth token somewhere.

For how to create your own loader, I have found an [article](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/show-loader-on-every-request-in-angular-2-9a0fca86afef) that goes through the steps of creating and implementing a loader. You can use this as a guide to creating a loader. You can just ignore the parts about implementing it with a custom `HttpService` because you won't need that since you're using the new Angular `HttpClient`.